# Extending ManyToManyField In Templates

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

I need to create a manytomany field that has some options and then next to each option there is an extra field

My models:

```py
class Subject(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    duration = models.IntegerField()
    price = models.IntegerField()

class Student(models.Model):
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    subject = models.ManyToManyField(Subject,through="StudentSubject")

class StudentSubject(models.Model)
    student = models.ForeignKey(Student,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    subject = models.ForeignKey(Subject,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    discount = models.IntegerField()
```

I used the intermediate model StudentSubject(this contains the extra field) but I'm not sure how I should render this in a template I want to do something like this:

```
Math DiscountField1
Physics DiscountField2
CompSci DiscountField3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can enumerate over the `StudentSubject` so for a student you can have:

```
{% for studentsubject in mystudent.studentsubject_set.all %}
    {{ studentsubject.subject.name }} {{ studentsubject.discount }}
{% endfor %}
```

with `mystudent`, the student for which you list the subjects with the corresponding discount.

You can boost efficiency by prefetching and selecting the related objects in the view, so:

```
from django.db.models import Prefetch
from django.shortcuts import render

def my_view(request, pk):
    qs = Student.objects.prefetch_related(
        Prefetch(
            'studentsubject_set',
            queryset=StudentSubject.objects.select_related('subject')
        )
    )
    mystudent = get_object_or_404(qs, pk=pk)
    # …
    return render(request, 'some-template.html', {'mystudent': mystudent})
```

Comment: I actually want to do something like this:
<form>
{% for subject in subjects %}
<label>{{subject}}</label> <input type="number" name="discountfield" />
{% endfor %}
</form>
however i want to render the discountfield as the StudentSubject's field, and then find a way to save it. Basically what I want to do is make a form that you can select a subject and add a discount

Comment: Then you should make a `ModelForm` for the `StudentSubject` model.

Comment: I could but I want to list each subject, if I created a ModelForm I would be able to select only 1 subject at the time. My goal is to add a checkbox next to each subject and add them that way to the Student model

Comment: @ppcase: no, you wrap that `ModelForm` in a `FormSet`, and then it with the `Subject` queryset. Furthermore if the discount is *per* subject: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/forms/formsets/

Comment: are you referring to something like this: StudentSubjectFormSet = formset_factory(StudentSubjectForm, extra=len(Subject.object.all()))?

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the intermediate model to the context:

```
context['student_subjects'] = StudentSubject.objects.select_related('subject').all()
```

Then in the template:

```
{% for s in student_subjects %}
    {{ s.subject.name }} {{ s.discount }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: it seems that I don't explain what I want to do very well, essentially I want to list all the subjects e.g. math,physics etc. and then next to each add a integerfield that's the discount, so each time a form is submitted it'll create a StudentSubject model that'll have that discount